# Backup a single file and overwrite if it exists with batch file in Windows

Tags: batch-file

The question could be a duplicate but I didn't find anything that explains it. I have a batch that changes hosts entries in Windows. Before it's doing that I want that it makes a copy in the same folder just as `hosts.bak` and if the backup already exists it should overwrite it.

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add rhis to your CMD script:

```
SET "_HostFile=%SystemRoot%\System32\Drivers\ETC\Hosts"
IF EXIST "%_Hostfile%.bak" (
  DEL /F "%_Hostfile%.bak" )
Copy "%_Hostfile%" "%_Hostfile%.bak"
```

Answer (score -1):

Just do:

```
Out-File .\fileToBackup.txt .\hosts.bak
```

Out-File by default overwrites a file if it exists

Comment: The bat file does not know Out-File @MichFont

Comment: This is powershell